# How to configure DynamoDB ProvisionedThroughput for multiple envs using Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm building serverless application on AWS and trying to create DynamoDB tables with certain values of ProvisionedThroughput or auto scaling enabled using Serverless Framework.

For example:

- RCU:1, WCU:1 for test env
- Auto Scaling(Min:5, Max:100, Target: 70%) for production env

I know how to configure settings for 1 environment by serverless.yml, but how can I manage different values for each environment using same serverless.yml file. Is it possible to change values or enable/disable auto scaling for each env in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the plugin

https://github.com/sbstjn/serverless-dynamodb-autoscaling

So, for the configuration you could use serverless variables like

```
custom:
  capacities:
    - table: CustomTable  # DynamoDB Resource
      index:              # List or single index name
        - custom-index-name
      read:
        minimum: ${file(../config.${self:provider.stage}.json):MinReadThroughput}
        maximum: ${file(../config.${self:provider.stage}.json):MaxReadThroughput}
        usage: 0.75
      write:
        minimum: 40       # Minimum write capacity
        maximum: 200      # Maximum write capacity
        usage: 0.5        # Targeted usage percentage


provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
```